# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo, all activities are registered in AndroidManifest.xml, dont know whats wrong

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android and i'm trying to run an app (simple test app), but get this error(. I have registered all my activities in AndroidManifest.xml and i'm using Android Studio 1.0.2

Here is the logcat of an app:

```
01-03 20:34:24.128  17300-17300/com.example.temur.sherlocked D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-03 20:34:24.134  17300-17300/com.example.temur.sherlocked E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.temur.sherlocked, PID: 17300
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.temur.sherlocked/com.example.temur.sherlocked.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.temur.sherlocked.MainActivity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.temur.sherlocked.MainActivity
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1559)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1892)
            at com.example.temur.sherlocked.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1559)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Code of MainActivity

```
    package com.example.temur.sherlocked;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        TextView infoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswer);

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

            if (requestCode==CHOOSE_THIEF){
                if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                    String thiefName = data.getStringExtra(SecondActivity.THIEF);
                    infoTextView.setText(thiefName);
                }else {
                    infoTextView.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
  static final private int CHOOSE_THIEF = 0;


    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent questionIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(questionIntent,CHOOSE_THIEF);
    }
}
```

Help me please :)

Comment: The main cause is `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`. Search for that and you might find an answer.

Comment: you have not installed `setContentView(R.layout.activity);` in the method `onCreate`

Comment: Post your code too..without it its difficult to know the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read other Stack Overflow questions, you will notice that well-written questions include the source code that is crashing (in your case, `MainActivity`) in addition to the stack trace.

In this case, I can tell just from the stack trace that you are calling `findViewById()` on your `MainActivity` too soon. This cannot be done until **after** your call to `setContentView()`.

In particular, you appear to be calling `findViewById()` in the initializer of data member. Do **not** call inherited methods on `Activity` until after `super.onCreate()`, unless specifically directed otherwise.

Comment: @temur_p: Per my answer, move `infoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswer);` to be inside the `onCreate()` method, after your `setContentView()` call.